# stop current run of useEffect and start the next one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was wondering if there is any way to break the current process of a UseEffect and have it start on the next render, like this

```
...
  useEffect(() => {
   SlowFunction(update);
  }, [update]);

setUpdate(1)
// a bit of time passes but not long enough for the SlowFunction(1) to be done
setUpdate(2)
//when this is called and the useEffect runs, stop the SlowFunction(1) and run SlowFunction(2)
```

my updated personal function is called in the use effect like so,

```
const [update, setUpdate] = useState(0);
  const [thisConst, setThisConst] = useState(0);

  async function SlowFunction(firstParam, paramEtc, { signal } = {}) {
    while (true) {
      //wait two seconds between each
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));

      // Before starting every individual "task" in the function,
      // first throw if the signal has been aborted. This will stop the function
      // if cancellation occurs:
      signal?.throwIfAborted();

      // else continue working...
      console.log('working on another iteration');
    }
    console.log('Completed!');
    return 'some value';
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;

    (async () => {
      try {
        const result = await SlowFunction(update, 'some other value', {
          signal,
        });
        setConst(result);
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log('EXCEPTION THROWN: ', ex);
      }
    })();

    return () => controller.abort(new Error('Starting next render'));
  }, [update]);
```

Comment: Do you have control over `SlowFunction`? The way to do this would be to have that function return something that cancels whatever it's doing and then use that cancel feature in the effect's _cleanup function_.

Comment: Ya let's say,
function SlowFunction( ){ 
// a long process
return result 
}
I am personally setting another const to SlowFunction( ) so setConst(SlowFunction(update))
so I can't change what the function returns

Comment: Oh okay, so there are two potential solutions: canceling the `SlowFunction` or just not calling `setConst` if you're on to another render. I'll write an answer with both options and we can discuss.

Comment: You'll need to design your `SlowFunction` to have a cancellable API (e.g. using the standard [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal)). We really can't answer this question without more detail. You'll need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AbortSignal` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) is the standard method for handling cancellation.

I'll provide an example of how to use it with a function like your `SlowFunction`. You'll need to accept an abort signal as an optional parameter so that when the next render occurs, the function can be cancelled.

Here's an example cancellable function:

```js
async function SlowFunction (firstParam, paramEtc, {signal} = {}) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i += 1) {
    // Before starting every individual "task" in the function,
    // first throw if the signal has been aborted. This will stop the function
    // if cancellation occurs:
    signal?.throwIfAborted();

    // else continue working...
    console.log('working on another iteration');
  }

  return 'some value';
}
```

You can use it in an effect hook like this: returning a cleanup function which invokes the `abort` method on the controller:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const {signal} = controller;

  (async () => {
    try {
      const result = await SlowFunction(update, 'some other value', {signal});
      setConst(result);
    }
    catch (ex) {
      // Catch the exception thrown when the next render starts
      // and the function hasn't completed yet.

      // Handle the exception if you need to,
      // or do nothing in this block if you don't.
    }
  })();

  return () => controller.abort(new Error('Starting next render'));
}, [update]);
```

If the function completes before the next render occurs, then the `abort` operation will have no effect, but if it hasn't yet, then the next time that the statement `signal?.throwIfAborted();` is reached, the function will throw an exception and terminate.

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74505547/stop-current-run-of-useeffect-and-start-the-next-one/74505869?noredirect=1#comment131532511_74505869):

If your JavaScript runtime is too old to support the [`AbortSignal.throwIfAborted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/throwIfAborted) method, you can work around that by replacing that line:

```js
signal?.throwIfAborted();
```

with:

```js
if (signal?.aborted) {
  throw signal?.reason ?? new Error('Operation was aborted');
}
```

Comment: it seems to not be running the function past signal?.throwIfAborted(); not ever running one iteration

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74505547/stop-current-run-of-useeffect-and-start-the-next-one/74505869?noredirect=1#comment131522084_74505869) Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: ya, It was too long to put here so I just placed it in the body of the question under "my updated personal function"

Comment: i am getting EXCEPTION THROWN:  [TypeError: signal.throwIfAborted is not a function. (In 'signal.throwIfAborted()', 'signal.throwIfAborted' is undefined)]

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74505547/stop-current-run-of-useeffect-and-start-the-next-one/74505869?noredirect=1#comment131532511_74505869) @JacksonStone It sounds like your runtime's JavaScript engine is older and doesn't support that method. I'll post an update to the answer with a workaround.